# Trying to make an for each if loop that checks to see if a certificate is soon expiring

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to make a powershell script that will check Azure Application Proxy certificates.

What i want to accomplish is that the script will show when a certificate is less then 30 days before expiring.

I have this so far

```
$aadapServPrinc = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Top 100000 | where-object {$_.Tags -Contains "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryOnPremApp"}  
$allApps = Get-AzureADApplication -Top 100000 
$aadapApp = $aadapServPrinc | ForEach-Object { $allApps -match $_.AppId} 

Write-Host "Displaying all custom domain Azure AD Application Proxy applications and the uploaded certificates..." -BackgroundColor "Black" -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-Host " "

# Get the list of SSL certificates assigned Azure AD Application Proxy applications

[string[]]$certs = $null



foreach ($item in $aadapApp) { 
    
    $tempApps = Get-AzureADApplicationProxyApplication -ObjectId $item.ObjectId
    $certs += $tempApps.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata
    $certsexpire + $tempApps.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata.ExpiryDate | Out-Null

    If ($tempApps.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata -match "class") {  }     
}  


Write-Host ("")
Write-Host ("Used certificates: ")
Write-Host ("")

$certs | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

This will list the certificates.

I have tried making a simple Get-Date, and converting it to UTC etc.
$tempApps.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata.ExpiryDate will output like this: `3/14/2022 10:59:00 PM`

I have tried something like this

```
$Today = Get-Date
$ExpiryDate = $tempApps.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata.ExpiryDate
[Datetime]$ExpiryDate = $ExpiryDate
$Diff = New-TimeSpan -Start $Today -End $ExpiryDate
```

I want my output to be like this:
Used certificates:
Show all certificates being used

IF ($Diff.days -lt 30))
Show which certificate is soon to expire.

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script example exports all app registrations secrets and certificates expiring beyond a required period for the specified apps from your directory in a CSV file non-interactively.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/scripts/powershell-export-apps-with-secrets-beyond-required

Answer (score 0):

First, do not make `$certs` a string array (i.e., `[string[]]$certs = $null`).  By doing this we limit the amount of data available to use later in the script.  Instead we should initialize it as an empty array by setting it equal to `@()` which is the called the [the array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1#the-array-sub-expression-operator)

```
$certs = @()
```

This allows us to add any type of object to it.  Doing this will allow us to capture full `VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata` objects later instead of just their `ToString()` value.

Now that we've done this the objects captured in `$certs` will already have the ExpiryDate property so you do not need to keep track of this separately in another variable.  `$certs` should be an array of MetaDataObjects.  At the end when you want to view which certs are going to expire within 30 days you can just loop through the certs and check their `ExpiryDate` properties.

You can use the below code which uses `Where-Object` to do this.  Inside the `Where-Object` FilterScript block `$_` is used to access the current item being processed from the pipeline.  We are checking if this object's `ExpiryDate` is greater than today's date - 30 days.  If it is it will be outputted to the screen.  Each object (cert) will be processed in this manner leaving you with a list of certs that will be expiring in the next 30 days.

```
$certs | Where-Object { $_.ExpiryDate -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30) }
```

It is at this point where you can cast the objects to string to convert them to their string representation if that is what you want.  `Foreach-Object` can be used for this.  Similar to Where-Object, we provide `Foreach-Object` with a scriptblock (called a process block for Foreach-Object) where action can be taken on each object using `$_`.

```
$certs | 
    Where-Object { $_.ExpiryDate -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30) } | 
        Foreach-Object { [string]$_ )
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. I learned alot, however when i do `

`$certs | Where-Object { $_.ExpiryDate -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30) }`

Instead of just `$certs | Sort-Object | Get-Unique` i doesnt output anything even though i change the days to a very high number. I can see that the $certs is filled, so i dont know why that happens

Comment: You're welcome.  Could be that the ExpiryDate is a string rather than a DateTime object?  I see below in your script that you cast to DateTime so maybe try `$certs | Where-Object { [DateTime]($_.ExpiryDate) -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-30) }`

Comment: `Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".
+ ... re-Object { [DateTime]($_.ExpiryDate) -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(- ...`

But yes its string, not datetime. But i cant seem to fill the variable it seems.

Comment: I don't have access to Azure so makes testing impossible for me.  [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplicationproxyapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) shows MetaData object should have a property called ExpiryDate and I'd have thought it would be a DateTime object.  Maybe this field actually just is null for the objects you are getting back?  Do you see anything in that field if you do `$certs.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata`.  Also what does it say for ExpiryDate when you do `$certs.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata | gm`

Comment: Also tried another way of doing it (pastebin is weird for me on chrome, so i had to use another browser
https://pastebin.com/d7pX5dti

returns displayname and this, but i cant for one weird reason get this expiry date.
https://imgur.com/a/DB0z44L

if i do $certs, i get a lot, if i do $certs.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata i get nothing

Comment: It looks like you got back expiry dates when you did `$certs.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata.ExpiryDate` so that's a start.  Can you do that 2nd command with the ` | gm` from my last comment and take a screenshot of that?

Comment: Looks very much like datetime

https://imgur.com/a/4kqooXt

Comment: Maybe we are talking over each other. I have two scripts, one was created after i made this, just to test.

heres number 1: https://pastebin.com/Tt6vfXLQ this is the original one, here i get no error, but it doesnt return any output even though i use -120 which it should, certs expiring in november.

number 2: https://pastebin.com/VRHudTCt, this displays the info correctly: https://imgur.com/a/DB0z44L but if i do 

`$list | Where-Object { $_.VerifiedCustomDomainCertificatesMetadata.ExpiryDate -gt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-120) }`